# Skype audio becomes distorted after other programs make sounds

Tags: windows, audio, skype

I have an HP laptop, [HP 250 G4](http://www8.hp.com/au/en/products/laptops/product-detail.html?oid=7609933). It came with Windows 8.1 and Skype but I've now upgraded it to Windows 10. The version of Skype that came with the laptop was so old that it didn't work at all with some sort of message saying that the latest version had to be downloaded and installed as it couldn't automatically update itself.

My current version of Skype is 7.18.0.109. Before that I was using 7.17.something, and before that 7.something. I will update it as soon as I am aware that there is a later version available. I have always had this problem on this laptop, even when running Windows 8.1 but I have only recently realised the trigger.

When I use Skype on the laptop the sound is fine unless any other sound plays, including system sounds caused by Skype. After the other sound stops the Skype sound becomes slow and distorted. If I generate another system sound, the Skype sound clears up until the other sound stops again. When the other person stops speaking, the sound will resynchronise itself. If they say a long farewell then hang up, their final words get cut off.

Completely exiting from Skype and restarting it usually clears up the problem. If the laptop is left alone for a few hours without restarting Skype the sound is OK on the next call. Otherwise, hanging up and immediately re-establishing the connection doesn't help.

I've tried asking on the Skype community but no-one answers. I had the same problem before upgrading to Windows 10 and Skype is the latest version available. No other program suffers from distorted sound, even at the same time as Skype is struggling. The only audio I'm using that didn't come with the laptop is a pair of earphones with a 3.5mm plug.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start a Skype call (video or audio)
2. Open the chat panel if it is hidden
3. After any amount of time (1 minute, 30 minutes, etc.) generate a sound with other software, e.g. a system sound by pressing one of the cursor keys in the empty chat box
4. The Skype call has been completely distortion free up to this point
5. While the other sound is playing, Skype will be distortion free, but distortion will happen as soon as the other sound stops
6. If the system sound is one second long, it is possible to hear one second of distortion free Skype by triggering the system sound again
7. The remainder of the call will have slow audio (gradually going out of sync with the video) and badly distorted, loud audio, except if another sound is playing at the same time

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish I'm happy to reinstall any problematic program because in my experience doing so has a 0.1% chance of improving the situation and a 1% chance of making things worse. I call this humouring the helpdesk operator. I'm editing my question because I didn't make it explicit that the problems started well before I upgraded Windows.

Comment: Hey @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish! I followed your instructions exactly and, guess what? It fixed my problem! I am, of course, lying through my keys. Reinstalling Skype made no difference whatsoever, it didn't even make anything worse. I've recorded a call to the Echo Service so if I can find somewhere to upload it to, you can hear exactly what it's doing.

Comment: I am going to regret making this comment, I just know it, knowing the answers to these two questions will help me formulate an answer ( if I have one ).  The first question have you attempted to install a Realtek driver which specifically indicates Windows 10 support?  Have you tried to use the Windows Store version of Skype?  Do these problems surface if you are booted into Safe Mode?

Comment: @CJDennis Great! Process of elimination wise, reinstalling the application didn't resolve your issue, thanks for trying and updating your question. It's usually always best to post in your question what you've already tried for showing what efforts you put into the task for potential resolution. Of course, before I go start chasing ghosts, unfortunately I always start with the simple and common tasks to ensure something simple or common isn't being overlooked as inconvenient rebooting the OS or reinstalling an application may be.

Comment: @CJDennis: I don't have a direct answer to your question, but I may be able to help you get one.  People volunteer their time to help others on the site.  When you cop an attitude and denigrate their efforts, you discourage responses.  Troubleshooting often involves trying things to rule stuff out.  If you think that process is stupid, just mutter to yourself instead of posting your mutterings here.  That's more likely to get you a solution.

Comment: @Ramhound You are awesome! Upgrading my Realtek Audio driver to the latest one (via Microsoft's auto-update) made the sound more distorted (in fact, completely unintelligible) but didn't affect the trigger. So I **downgraded** the audio driver from 6.0.1.7455 (the originally supplied driver) to 6.0.1.7335 from the HP website and now the sound is perfect in Skype no matter how much I try to break it! Merci beaucoup ! Feel free to write it up as an answer and I'll give you the rep for the correct answer.

Comment: Since I feel exactly what fixer1234 describes, feel free to answer the question yourself, any answer I submit would be a wiki anyways.

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me exactly the same way, BUT.... there is a simple solution:
as it is linked to the windows system sounds (as soon as one of those sounds goes on, skype sound continue distorted and video also ...), simply configure it as "no sounds" ... problem solved. your skype conversations will go on smoothly, no distorsions anymore ;-)

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score -1):

o.k. after days and 25 downloads  I found the solution.  uninstall Skype.  Download Skype version  6.14 thats the one that works falawless.No mor distorsion, just loud and clear.  Good luck folks.